# Output voltage of BJT shunt regulator in terms of input voltage

Tags: bjt, shunt

I am working through a tutorial to prepare for a test tomorrow and am completely stumped with a step in the algebra.
The question is in the image below

[image]

I am trying to complete b).

I have understood the steps so far following the answer sheet however am stuck on this last step and would greatly appreciate some help understanding the algebra.
The below image is the steps I have completed

[image]

I am stuck on how I get from the top line of the next image onwards, how does Vbe+Vz in the second expression get cancelled out?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, write the input voltage equation:

$$
\mathrm{
V_{in}=I \ R_1+I_B\ r_Z+V_Z+V_{BE} \\
I=I_B \ (1+h_{FE}) \\
\Rightarrow V_{in}=I_B(r_Z+(1+h_{FE})R_1)+V_Z+V_{BE}
}
$$

Since \$\mathrm{r_Z<<h_{FE} \ R_1}\$, we can simplify the above as

$$
\mathrm{
V_{in}=I_B(1+h_{FE})\ R_1 + (V_Z+V_{BE})
}
$$

Now, write the output voltage equation:

$$
\mathrm{
V_{out}=I_B\ r_Z + (V_Z+V_{BE})
}
$$

Replace the \$\mathrm{I_B}\$ here with the one obtained from the input voltage equation:

$$
\mathrm{
V_{out}=\Bigg(\frac{V_{in}-(V_Z+V_{BE})}{(1+h_{FE})\ R_1} \Bigg)r_Z+ (V_Z+V_{BE})
}
$$

Now, for simplicity, I'm doing these replacements: \$\mathrm{V_Z+V_{BE}=V_X}\$ and \$\mathrm{(1+h_{FE})R_1=hR}\$. The rest is algebra:

$$
\mathrm{
V_{out}=\Bigg(\frac{V_{in}-V_X}{hR} \Bigg)r_Z+ V_X =\frac{V_{in}\ r_Z-V_X \ r_Z+V_X \ hR}{hR} \\ 
=\frac{V_{in}\ r_Z+V_X(hR-r_Z)}{hR}
}
$$

Again, since we know that \$\mathrm{r_Z<<(1+h_{FE}) \ R_1 = hR}\$:

$$
\mathrm{
V_{out}=\frac{V_{in}\ r_Z+V_X(hR-r_Z)}{hR}=\frac{V_{in}\ r_Z+V_X(hR)}{hR} \\
=V_{in}\frac{r_Z}{hR}+V_X \\
=V_{in}\frac{r_Z}{(1+h_{FE}) \ R_1} + V_{BE}+V_Z
}
$$

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful.